# Issue with links and milestones in Gantt chart

Tags: pgfgantt

I am currently using pgfgantt to add a Gantt chart to a Latex document. The chart spans a period of just under a year. I have used the code from  ([Getting gantt chart week to show week number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230968/getting-gantt-chart-week-to-show-week-number)) to add week numbers and its working fine. I have two problems that I would like to solve:

- milestones are almost invisible
- I would prefer straight line, such as link type to (f-s), however without text (to avoid clutter).

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfgantt}
  \title{Gantt Chart}
  \begin{document}

  \newcounter{myWeekNum}
  \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
  %
  \newcommand{\myWeek}{\themyWeekNum
          \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
          \ifnum\themyWeekNum=53
          \setcounter{myWeekNum}{1}
          \else\fi
  }
  \setcounter{myWeekNum}{26}
  \ganttset{%
          calendar week text={\myWeek{}}%
  }
  \begin{figure}[h!bt]
          \caption{Time Plan}
          \begin{center}
                  \begin{ganttchart}[
                          vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
                          hgrid={dotted},
                          x unit=.08cm,
                          y unit title=.6cm,
                          y unit chart=1cm,
                          time slot format=isodate,
                          link/.style={->, ultra thick},
                          link bulge=4,
                          time slot format/start date=2017-07-01]{2017-07-01}{2018-06-30}
                          \ganttset{bar height=.6}
                          \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week} \\
                          \ganttmilestone[name=e0]{Start}{2017-07-03} \\
                          \ganttbar[name=e1]{Task01}{2017-07-03}{2017-08-15} \\
                          \ganttbar[name=e2]{Task02}{2017-08-01}{2017-08-08}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e3]{Task03}{2017-08-01}{2017-12-29}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e4]{Task04}{2017-08-01}{2017-08-15}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e5]{Task05}{2017-08-16}{2017-08-31}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e6]{Task06}{2017-09-01}{2017-09-21}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e7]{Task07}{2017-09-22}{2017-10-31}\\
                          \ganttmilestone[name=e8]{M1}{2017-11-01}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e9]{Task08}{2017-11-01}{2017-11-14}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e10]{Task09}{2017-11-01}{2017-12-22}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e11]{Task10}{2017-12-25}{2018-01-01}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e12]{Task11}{2018-01-02}{2018-01-05}\\
                          \ganttmilestone[name=e13]{M2}{2018-01-08}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e14]{Task14}{2018-01-08}{2018-02-07}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e15]{Task15}{2018-02-08}{2018-03-14}\\
                          \ganttmilestone[name=e16]{M3}{2018-03-15}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e17]{Task17}{2018-03-15}{2018-05-14}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e18]{Task18}{2018-05-15}{2018-05-23}\\
                          \ganttbar[name=e19]{Task19}{2018-05-24}{2018-05-31}
                          \ganttlink[link mid=.8]{e3}{e16}
                          \ganttlink[link type=-]{e4}{e5}
                          \ganttlink{e5}{e6}
                          \ganttlink{e6}{e7}
                          \ganttlink{e7}{e8}
                          \ganttlink{e8}{e9}
                          \ganttlink{e8}{e10}
                          \ganttlink{e10}{e11}
                          \ganttlink{e11}{e12}
                          \ganttlink{e12}{e13}
                          \ganttlink{e13}{e14}
                          \ganttlink{e14}{e15}
                          \ganttlink{e15}{e16}
                          \ganttlink{e16}{e17}
                          \ganttlink{e17}{e18}
                          \ganttlink{e18}{e19}
                  \end{ganttchart}
          \end{center}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image: Gantt chart]

Do you have any pointers?

Comment: I don't fully understand your second requirement, for the first one, add `milestone/.append style={inner ysep=3mm}`

Comment: Thanks for your help on the first point, adding that code fixed the milestones. With regards to the second point, I would like to have straight arrows like: \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{e5}{e6} but without the "Finish to Start" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1., add `milestone/.append style={inner ysep=3mm},` to the chart settings.

For 2. you can make a new type of link based on e.g. `f-s`, and set the text label to be empty:

```
\newganttlinktypealias{straight}{f-s}
\setganttlinklabel{straight}{}
```

Add those before the `ganttchart`, and use `link type=straight`.

A shortened complete example, so it's easier to see:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{myWeekNum}
\stepcounter{myWeekNum}
%
\newcommand{\myWeek}{\themyWeekNum
        \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
        \ifnum\themyWeekNum=53
        \setcounter{myWeekNum}{1}
        \else\fi
}
\setcounter{myWeekNum}{26}
\ganttset{%
        calendar week text={\myWeek{}}%
}

% define a new link type
\newganttlinktypealias{straight}{f-s}
% remove label
\setganttlinklabel{straight}{}
\begin{ganttchart}[
            vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
            hgrid={dotted},
            x unit=.08cm,
            y unit title=.6cm,
            y unit chart=1cm,
            time slot format=isodate,
            link/.style={->, ultra thick},
            link bulge=4,
            time slot format/start date=2017-07-01,
            milestone/.append style={inner ysep=3mm}, % <-- added
             ]{2017-06-15}{2017-09-03}
            \ganttset{bar height=.6}
            \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week} \\
            \ganttmilestone[name=e0]{Start}{2017-07-03} \\
            \ganttbar[name=e1]{Task01}{2017-07-03}{2017-07-15}\\
            \ganttbar[name=e2]{Task02}{2017-07-16}{2017-08-01}\\
            \ganttbar[name=e4]{Task04}{2017-08-02}{2017-08-15}\\

           \ganttlink{e0}{e1} 
           \ganttlink[link type=-]{e1}{e2} 
           \ganttlink[link type=straight]{e2}{e4}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```