# pgfgantt: How to display week numbers according to ISO 8601 counting scheme?

Tags: counters, pgfgantt

In addition to the calendarian month names, I added a [calendarian week counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231091) (week 1 up to week 52) into the title of a `pgfgantt`-chart.

**Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newcounter{resetWeekNum}
\stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
\newcommand{\resetWeek}{ %
    \theresetWeekNum
    \stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
    \ifnum\theresetWeekNum=53
    \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{1}
    \else\fi
}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{27}
    \ganttset{calendar week text=\scriptsize{\resetWeek{}}}

    \begin{ganttchart}
                        [   time slot format    =   isodate,
                            x unit              =   2mm,
                            vgrid               =   true,
                        ]   {2019-07-01}{2021-05-16}

        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name,week=1 day} \\ % weekday=letter
        \ganttbar{WP1}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-27} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-31} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2021-01-03} \\

    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result (year 2019 - 2020):**

[image: Screenshot of the result 1]

**Screenshot of the result (year 2020 - 2021):**

[image]

---

**Description of the issue:**

While the current week `counter` works completely fine for years 2019 to 2020 (counting `52` weeks for 2019), there is some small failure from 2020 to 2021 (falsely counting `52` weeks instead of `53` weeks).

The problem:

According to international week counting standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering), the *first calendarian week* of each year is the week that contains the *first Thursday of the year*. After that, the next counted week starts on Monday (= as the second calendarian week). Therefore: 2019 has `52` weeks while 2020 has `53` weeks.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering):

"*ISO 8601 includes the ISO week date system, a numbering system for weeks – each week begins on a Monday and is associated with the year that contains that week's Thursday (so that if a year starts in a long weekend Friday–Sunday, week number one of the year will start after that). For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) ran from Monday, 29 December 2003 to Sunday, 4 January 2004, because its Thursday was 1 January 2004, whereas week 1 of 2005 (2005W01) ran from Monday, 3 January 2005 to Sunday, 9 January 2005, because its Thursday was 6 January 2005 and so the first Thursday of 2005.*"

**The question:**

How can I display calendarian week numbers in consideration of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) standard counting scheme?

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand the problem. The weeks are numbered 1, 2, ... The last week of year gets labeled 1 if it overlaps with the next year since then it is week one of the next year. Where precisely do you want to see a `53`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Thanks for the hint! Please see my updated question... Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Steven that this may be some sort of an overkill. On the other hand the `calendar` library has the nice `\pgfcalendarifdate` built in, so...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newif\ifspecialweek
\newcounter{resetWeekNum}
\stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
\newcommand{\resetWeek}{ %
    \theresetWeekNum
    \stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
    \specialweekfalse
    \pgfcalendarifdate{31-12-\startyear}{Thursday}{\global\specialweektrue}{}
    \pgfcalendarifdate{31-12-\startyear}{Friday}{\global\specialweektrue}{}
    \pgfcalendarifdate{31-12-\startyear}{Saturday}{\global\specialweektrue}{}
    \pgfcalendarifdate{31-12-\startyear}{Sunday}{\global\specialweektrue}{}
    \ifspecialweek
      \ifnum\theresetWeekNum=54
      \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{1}
      \fi
    \else
      \ifnum\theresetWeekNum=53
      \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{1}
      \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{27}
    \ganttset{calendar week text=\scriptsize{\resetWeek}}

    \begin{ganttchart}
                        [   time slot format    =   isodate,
                            x unit              =   2mm,
                            vgrid               =   true,
                        ]   {2019-07-01}{2021-05-16}

        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name,week=1 day} \\ % weekday=letter
        \ganttbar{WP1}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-27} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-31} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2021-01-03} \\

    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since the 53-week year happens only occasionally and never in quick succession, I think in this case, it is easier to hardwire 53 weeks for the particular case when `\ifnum\startyear=2020` rather than develop an ISO 8601-compliant version.  It is the former course which I have done in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newcounter{resetWeekNum}
\stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
\newcommand{\resetWeek}{ %
    \theresetWeekNum
    \stepcounter{resetWeekNum}
    \ifnum\startyear=2020
      \ifnum\theresetWeekNum=54
      \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{1}
      \else\fi
    \else
      \ifnum\theresetWeekNum=53
      \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{1}
      \else\fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{resetWeekNum}{27}
    \ganttset{calendar week text=\scriptsize{\resetWeek{}}}

    \begin{ganttchart}
                        [   time slot format    =   isodate,
                            x unit              =   2mm,
                            vgrid               =   true,
                        ]   {2019-07-01}{2021-05-16}

        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name,week=1 day} \\ % weekday=letter
        \ganttbar{WP1}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-27} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2020-12-31} \\
        \ganttbar{WP2}{2019-04-01}{2021-01-03} \\

    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An additional approach is coming directly from the package developer Wolfgang Esser-Skala as an answer to my request:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}


\makeatletter

\newcount\@tempcntc

\def\@rawjuliantocalendarweek#1{%
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax%
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{#1}{\@tempa}{\@tempb}{\@tempc}%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\@tempa-01-01+-1}{\@tempcntb}%
  \advance\@tempcnta by-\@tempcntb\relax% @tempcnta = ordinal date of start date
  \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{#1}{\@tempcntb}%
  \advance\@tempcntb by1\relax% @tempcntb = week day number of start date
  \pgfmathparse{int((\@tempcnta - \@tempcntb + 10) / 7)}%
}

\def\pgfcalendarjuliantocalendarweek#1#2{%
  \begingroup%
  \@rawjuliantocalendarweek{#1}%
  \@tempcnta=\pgfmathresult\relax%
  \ifnum\@tempcnta=0\relax%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{#1}{\@tempa}{\@tempb}{\@tempc}%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\@tempa-01-01+-1}{\@tempcntc}%
    \@rawjuliantocalendarweek{\@tempcntc}%
  \else\ifnum\@tempcnta=53\relax%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{#1}{\@tempa}{\@tempb}{\@tempc}%
    \pgfcalendarifdate{\@tempa-12-31}{Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday}{%
      \relax%
    }{%
      \def\pgfmathresult{1}%
    }%
  \fi\fi%
  \global#2=\pgfmathresult\relax%
  \endgroup%
}

\ganttset{
  calendar/calendarweek/.code={%
    \ifgtt@calendar@eol\ganttnewline\fi%
    \begingroup%
    \gtt@calendar@slots=1\relax%
    \pgfcalendar{}{\gtt@calendar@startdate}{\gtt@calendar@enddate}{%
      \ifdate{Sunday}{%
        \gtt@calendar@startofweek=\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian\relax%
        \advance\gtt@calendar@startofweek by1\relax%
        \advance\gtt@calendar@startofweek by-\gtt@calendar@slots\relax%
        \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\gtt@calendar@startofweek}%
          {\startyear}{\startmonth}{\startday}%
        \pgfcalendarjuliantocalendarweek{\gtt@calendar@startofweek}{\@tempcnta}%
        \def\currentweek{\the\@tempcnta}%
        \gantttitle{%
          \ganttvalueof{calendar week text}%
        }{%
          \the\gtt@calendar@slots%
        }%
        \gtt@calendar@slots=1\relax%
      }{%
        \advance\gtt@calendar@slots by1%
      }%
      \ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarendiso}{%
        \ifnum\gtt@calendar@slots=1\relax\else%
          \advance\gtt@calendar@slots by-1\relax%
          \gtt@calendar@startofweek=\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian\relax%
          \advance\gtt@calendar@startofweek by1\relax%
          \advance\gtt@calendar@startofweek by-\gtt@calendar@slots\relax%
          \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\gtt@calendar@startofweek}%
            {\startyear}{\startmonth}{\startday}%
          \pgfcalendarjuliantocalendarweek{\gtt@calendar@startofweek}{\@tempcnta}%
          \def\currentweek{\the\@tempcnta}%
          \gantttitle{%
            \ganttvalueof{calendar week text}%
          }{%
            \the\gtt@calendar@slots%
          }%
        \fi%
      }{}%
    }%
    \endgroup%
    \gtt@calendar@eoltrue%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newcount\mycount

\begin{ganttchart}[
        hgrid,
        vgrid,
        x unit=4mm,
        time slot format=isodate
    ]{2019-12-20}
     {2020-01-20}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, calendarweek, day}
\end{ganttchart}

\noindent
\pgfcalendar{cal}
  {2012-12-24}
  {2013-01-07}{%
  \pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentday~%
  \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}~%
  \pgfcalendarjuliantocalendarweek{\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian}{\mycount}\the\mycount%
  \ifdate{Sunday}{\\[\baselineskip]}{\\}%
}

%\pgfcalendarjuliantocalendarweek{}

\end{document}
```